# Restore OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I do not like Mountain Lion because some of my paid old software will not run. Is there a way I downgrade back to OS X 10.6 if I don't have the original install disks and I did not take a single Time Machine backup?  I thought there was a restore partition that had the original OS.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

Recovery partitions were first introduced in 10.7. Your only option is to acquire the OS X Snow Leopard installer "somewhere else", then completely erase your hard drive, and install 10.6 fresh.

It is advised to keep backups at all times, especially before doing a major system upgrade.

Comment: Would, say, borrowing a friend's SL disc be technically with or against Apple's licensing rules? Does anyone know?

Comment: If your Mac came with SL (or you bought it), you have the license irrespective of the installer, so it should be fine. But IANAL :)

Comment: Just wanted to add that you can buy 10.6 for $19.99 from the Apple Store.